# webpack typescript configuration template and style need a loader

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack

I've configured a Vue project from scratch with Webpack and typescript and don't understand why I got errors while adding a `<template>` element in my .vue file and a `<style>` element that makes my webpack watcher displaying errors

Here is the error : 
[image]

Here is my webpack.config.js file :

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
            'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax',
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone encounter the same problem, it was because of the version that I was using of `vue-loader` I was using v15 and I needed the 14 one